# marking events on time series

Tags: plotting, time-series

Suppose I have a time series (say, for the sake of argument, the stock time series of AAPL for the last thirty years or so), and I want to mark (with some sort of a highlight, or flag, or whatever) pivotal events (Steve Jobs comes back, iMac released, iPhone released, etc). Is there a reasonably civilized way of doing that? This is a pretty common thing to do on Bloomberg terminal and such.

Comment: Have you seen [`Callout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html)?

Comment: @Edmund I had not, but I have now, thanks!